# How to create Crystal Report in ASP.NET MVC using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I am struggling to create my report well here and need some help, I have this method and want my file extension not be PDF but rather XML. I attempted using this below logic and still not getting it right on my `SetDataSource`.

```
public ActionResult Download_XMLReport()
{
    eNtsaRegistration context = new eNtsaRegistration();

    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    rpt.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "AcademyReports.rpt"));
    rpt.SetDataSource(from TrainingRegForm in context.TrainingRegs.Take(5) select TrainingRegForm);

    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    rpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;
    rpt.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(5, 5, 5, 5));
    rpt.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA5;

    Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(stream, "application/xml", "eNtsaReportTrainingForm.xml");
}

// Table from the Database.
public class TrainingRegForm
{
        *[Key]
        public Guid? Id { get; set; } // Must this be now public abstract Guid Guid {get;set;}...??*
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddressLine { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StateProvince { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string CellNumber { get; set; }
        public string DietaryRequirement { get; set; }
}
```

// Additional GUI as requrested below by Nadeem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
public ActionResult Download_XMLReport()
        {
            eNtsaRegistration context = new eNtsaRegistration();

            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();    
            var result =(from TrainingRegForm in context.TrainingRegs.Take(5) select
                  TrainingRegForm).ToList(); 

            rpt.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "AcademyReports.rpt"));
            rpt.SetDataSource(result); 
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            rpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;
            rpt.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(5, 5, 5, 5));
            rpt.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA5;

            Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);




            return File(stream, "application/xml", "eNtsaReportTrainingForm.xml");
        }
```

Kindly share the snapshot. I have attached sample snapshot for your reference.
[image: SampleImageRequiredForProvidingWorkaround]

Community will work to resolve the issue or provide workaround to achieve your result.

[WorkingWithGUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.guid?view=netcore-3.1)

//####----This is Just the TEST Run.

Step 1) Create a new class

```
public class TrainingRegFormInfo
{

        public int w_Id { get; set; }
        public string w_Title { get; set; }
        public string w_FirstName { get; set; }
        public string w_LastName { get; set; }
        public string w_Position { get; set; }
        public string w_Company { get; set; }

        public string w_StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string w_StreetAddressLine { get; set; }
        public string w_City { get; set; }
        public string w_StateProvince { get; set; }
        public int w_ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string w_Email { get; set; }

        public string w_CellNumber { get; set; }
        public string w_DietaryRequirement { get; set; }

}
```

Step 2)

```
public ActionResult Download_XMLReport()
        {
         var _db = new eNtsaRegistration(); 

              var data = (from q in _db.TrainingRegForm
                        select new InvoiceInfo
                        {
              w_Title = q.DB_COLUMN_NAME,
              w_FirstName = q.DB_COLUMN_NAME,
            }).ToList();


            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();    
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/AcademyReports.rpt"));
            rpt.SetDataSource(data); 
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();


    try
            {
            Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/xml", "eNtsaReportTrainingForm.xml");
            }
    catch
            {
                throw;
            }
     }
```

Step 3) Database Expert
a)create new data source for TrainingRegFormInfo Class and add their
fields to report.

Step 4) Please share snapshot of error. I am sure you will get the result. If Yes then we together will work on your stuff.

Comment: Nadeem i am getting a throw error exception in line rpt.SetDataSource(result) "DataSet does not support nullable". But i cant be because of my data type as Gui? int ID {get;set;} on my table definition. On the DB that field as default values as unique primary Key.

Comment: can you re-produce the same error? By creating a test table having <Nullable>int ID {get; set;).  may be you will ask? Why I do this?. I will say. If you see results it means at CR designer properly configured using expert explorer. There is a very tiny part of tricky configuration for data source for proper adding to your project.

Comment: I had a walk around this but now i am getting this error now "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
  HResult=0x8013193C
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.TrainingRegForms'.

"

Comment: can you share snapshot. please review answer section I have attached sample snap for your reference.

Comment: i have attached the document screen shot, what could i be missing here. I have tried to replicate the problem using unique name, still getting the same results as yesterday.

Comment: I got it. and correct me if I am wrong you do not need GUID on report?. furthermore, if you kindly recheck my sample snap i have numbered 1,2,3. If you share snap this way will definitely try to provide workaround to achieve your goal.

Comment: You did, show me how. GUI just for display the field once the report is downloaded. I was think of re downloading the crystal report. then its not a best practise.

Comment: Can you please do one more thing. I have updated the answer. Started from //####----This is Just the TEST Run. Please do that and I will catch you later today.

Comment: Nadeem if possible have a look at this issue now i m getting. Used ur test logic. System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaRegForm' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

Comment: downloading and re-installation of CR is not the issue. I am very much positive that CR properly sync with your VS environment. The current issue is resolve in many forum i just googled and came across too many answers. The only thing bothers me is .DAL.eNtsaRegForm. where it is coming from and I would not ask you because you will say I dont know. Let me think and will share more information or findings later this weekend.